# Select tag for @group in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for, html-select

I've got a select type with 3 fixed options as a clock-type. I can't figure out how to get the clocktype(Which is in my group model) to function properly.

In my HTML it shows the select name as `clocktype`. In stead of `group[clocktype]`.

Here's my form:

```
<%= form_for(@group) do |f| %>
  <% if @group.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@group.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this group from being saved:</h2>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <%= select_tag(:clocktype, options_for_select([['one', 1], ['two', 2], ['three', 3]])) %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `f.` at the front, ie. `f.select`. This will associate the select tag to the form you've created. Using `select_tag` alone is for generic forms not specifically associated with a model.

Comment: I tried that. with `f.select_tag` which resulted in an error. Using `f.select`. Did the trick. Thanks!